# How to iterate over arbitrary number of files in parallel in python?

Tags: python, loops

I have a list of file objects in a list called `paths`

I'd like to be able to go through and read the first line of each file, do something with this n-tuple of data, then move on the second line of each file. The number of file objects in `path` is arbitrary.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools
for line_tuple in itertools.izip(*files):
    whatever()
```

I'd use `zip`, but that would read the entire contents of the files into memory. Note that `files` should be a list of file objects; I'm not sure what you mean by "list of file handlers".

Comment: I meant to say "file descriptor" or "file object" like you said. I edited my original and changed "file handler" to "file object". Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This depends on how "arbitrary" it actually is.  As long as the number is less than the limit of your OS, then `itertools.izip` should work just fine (or `itertools.izip_longest` as appropriate).

```
files = [open(f) for f in filenames]
for lines in itertools.izip(*files):
    # do something

for f in files:
    f.close()
```

If you can have more files than your OS will allow you to open, then you're out of luck (at least as far as an easy solution is concerned).

Comment: python3.x compatibility note:  `itertools.izip` -> `zip` and `itertools.izip_longest` -> `itertools.zip_longest`.

Answer (score 0):

the first idea pop into my mind the following code , it seems too Straightforward

```
fp_list = []
for file in path_array:
    fp = open(file)
    fp_list.append(fp)

line_list = []
for fp in fp_list:
    line = fp.readline()
    line_list.append(line)
    ## you code here process the line_list

for fp in fp_list:
    fp.close()
```